# Why unneeded XHTML and JS, axd comes in Asp.NET pages?

Tags: php, asp.net, xhtml, semantics, sitecore

Can anyone explain why it comes? it makes source code lengthy and it will affect to site SEO also. Site is using [Sitecore CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/en/Products/Sitecore-CMS.aspx)

Is this fault of .NET framework or Sitecore CMS?

Is PHP and other technology better to produce clean, semantic and W3C valid code?

These extra info in header (what is the use of these)

```
<head>
    <meta name="CODE_LANGUAGE" content="C#" />
    <meta name="vs_defaultClientScript" content="JavaScript" />
    <meta name="vs_targetSchema" content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" />
</head>
```

So much unneeded xhtml, JavaScript code just after body, why such a long code just after body?

```
    <body>
        <form name="MainForm" method="post" action="/en/site-services/alert.aspx" id="MainForm">
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEwMTk1MTQ1MDUPZBYGZg8VARdBbGVydCAgQm9va2VyIEdyb3VwIFBMQ2QCBg8VAQVhbGVydGQCBxBkZBYCAgEPZBYCAgEPZBYCZg9kFgJmDw8WAh4FQ2xhc3MFDWdsb2JhbFdyYXBwZXIWAh4FY2xhc3MFDWdsb2JhbFdyYXBwZXIWAmYPZBYGZg9kFgJmD2QWAmYPDxYCHwAFD0hlYWRlckNvbnRhaW5lchYCHwEFD0hlYWRlckNvbnRhaW5lchYCZg9kFgICAg8PFgQeCENzc0NsYXNzBQZTZWFyY2geBF8hU0ICAmQWAmYPDxYCHwAFG1NlYXJjaEdlbmVyYWxFcnJvckNvbnRhaW5lchYCHwEFG1NlYXJjaEdlbmVyYWxFcnJvckNvbnRhaW5lcmQCAQ9kFgJmD2QWAmYPDxYCHwAFE1R3b0NvbHVtbnNDb250YWluZXIWAh8BBRNUd29Db2x1bW5zQ29udGFpbmVyFgRmDw8WAh8ABRpUd29Db2x1bW5zTGVmdENvbENvbnRhaW5lchYCHwEFGlR3b0NvbHVtbnNMZWZ0Q29sQ29udGFpbmVyZAIBDw8WAh8ABRtUd29Db2x1bW5zUmlnaHRDb2xDb250YWluZXIWAh8BBRtUd29Db2x1bW5zUmlnaHRDb2xDb250YWluZXIWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYEZg9kFhBmDw8WBB8ABSlhbGVydHNJbnZhbGlkRW1haWxBZGRyZXNzTWVzc2FnZUNvbnRhaW5lch4JX19WaXNpYmxlaBYCHwEFKWFsZXJ0c0ludmFsaWRFbWFpbEFkZHJlc3NNZXNzYWdlQ29udGFpbmVyZAIBDw8WBB8ABRhhbGVydHNMb2dpbkZhaWxDb250YWluZXIfBGgWAh8BBRhhbGVydHNMb2dpbkZhaWxDb250YWluZXJkAgIPDxYEHwAFG2FsZXJ0c0xvZ2luU3VjY2Vzc0NvbnRhaW5lch8EaBYCHwEFG2FsZXJ0c0xvZ2luU3VjY2Vzc0NvbnRhaW5lchYGZg8PFgIfAAUhYWxlcnRzTG9naW5TdWNjZXNzQmVmb3JlQ29udGFpbmVyFgIfAQUhYWxlcnRzTG9naW5TdWNjZXNzQmVmb3JlQ29udGFpbmVyZAIBDw8WAh8ABR9hbGVydHNMb2dpblN1Y2Nlc3NFZGl0Q29udGFpbmVyFgIfAQUfYWxlcnRzTG9naW5TdWNjZXNzRWRpdENvbnRhaW5lcmQCAg8PFgIfAAUgYWxlcnRzTG9naW5TdWNjZXNzQWZ0ZXJDb250YWluZXIWAh8BBSBhbGVydHNMb2dpblN1Y2Nlc3NBZnRlckNvbnRhaW5lcmQCAw8PFgQfAAUkYWxlcnRzU3VjY2Vzc2Z1bGx5Q29tcGxldGVkQ29udGFpbmVyHwRoFgIfAQUkYWxlcnRzU3VjY2Vzc2Z1bGx5Q29tcGxldGVkQ29udGFpbmVyZAIEDw8WBB8ABSBhbGVydHNBbHJlYWR5RXhpc3RzVXNlckNvbnRhaW5lch8EaBYCHwEFIGFsZXJ0c0FscmVhZHlFeGlzdHNVc2VyQ29udGFpbmVyZAIFDw8WBB8ABSFhbGVydHNVbnN1YnNjcmliZU1lc3NhZ2VDb250YWluZXIfBGgWAh8BBSFhbGVydHNVbnN1YnNjcmliZU1lc3NhZ2VDb250YWluZXJkAgYPZBYEAgEPZBYCZg9kFgJmDw8WBB8ABRphbGVydHNVbnN1YnNjcmliZUNvbnRhaW5lch8EaBYCHwEFGmFsZXJ0c1Vuc3Vic2NyaWJlQ29udGFpbmVyFgRmDw8WAh8ABSBhbGVydHNVbnN1YnNjcmliZUhlYWRlckNvbnRhaW5lchYCHwEFIGFsZXJ0c1Vuc3Vic2NyaWJlSGVhZGVyQ29udGFpbmVyZAIBDw8WAh8ABR1hbGVydHNVbnN1YnNjcmliZUJ0bkNvbnRhaW5lchYCHwEFHWFsZXJ0c1Vuc3Vic2NyaWJlQnRuQ29udGFpbmVyZAIVD2QWAgIBD2QWAmYPEGRkFgFmZAIHDw8WAh8ABR5hbGVydHNBbGVydERpc2NsYWltZXJDb250YWluZXIWAh8BBR5hbGVydHNBbGVydERpc2NsYWltZXJDb250YWluZXJkAgEPDxYCHgRUZXh0BZoEPHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPSJ0ZXh0L2phdmFzY3JpcHQiPg0KZnVuY3Rpb24gU2VsZWN0QWxsKHN0cmFydFdpdGgsIHRvdGFsLCBTZWxlY3RlQWxsQ2hrKQ0Kew0KICAgICBmb3IodmFyIGkgPTE7aTw9dG90YWw7aSsrKQ0KICAgICB7DQogICAgICAgICBkb2N1bWVudC5nZXRFbGVtZW50QnlJZChzdHJhcnRXaXRoICsgaSkuY2hlY2tlZCA9IGRvY3VtZW50LmdldEVsZW1lbnRCeUlkKFNlbGVjdGVBbGxDaGspLmNoZWNrZWQ7DQogICAgIH0NCn0NCg0KZnVuY3Rpb24gU2VsZWN0T25lKHN0cmFydFdpdGgsIHRvdGFsLCBTZWxlY3RlQWxsQ2hrKQ0Kew0KICAgICB2YXIgaTsNCiAgICAgZm9yKGkgPTE7aTw9dG90YWw7aSsrKQ0KICAgICB7DQogICAgICAgICBpZighZG9jdW1lbnQuZ2V0RWxlbWVudEJ5SWQoc3RyYXJ0V2l0aCArIGkpLmNoZWNrZWQpDQogICAgICAgICAgICAgYnJlYWs7DQogICAgIH0NCiAgICAgZG9jdW1lbnQuZ2V0RWxlbWVudEJ5SWQoU2VsZWN0ZUFsbENoaykuY2hlY2tlZCA9ICgodG90YWwrMSkgPT0gaSk7DQp9DQo8L3NjcmlwdD4NCmRkAgIPZBYCZg9kFgJmDw8WAh8ABQ9Gb290ZXJDb250YWluZXIWAh8BBQ9Gb290ZXJDb250YWluZXIWAmYPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAmYPDxYCHwAFDldyYXBwZXJXcmFwcGVyFgIfAQUOV3JhcHBlcldyYXBwZXJkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYOBTFib2R5XzEkZ2xvYmFsXzAkaGVhZGVyaGVhZGVyXzIkU2VhcmNoU3VibWl0QnV0dG9uBTVib2R5XzEkZ2xvYmFsXzEkdHdvY29sdW1uc3JpZ2h0XzMkYWxlcnRzQ2F0ZWdvcnlDaGtfMQU1Ym9keV8xJGdsb2JhbF8xJHR3b2NvbHVtbnNyaWdodF8zJGFsZXJ0c0NhdGVnb3J5Q2hrXzIFPGJvZHlfMSRnbG9iYWxfMSR0d29jb2x1bW5zcmlnaHRfMyRhbGVydHNSTlNTZWxlY3RBbGxDaGVja2JveAU4Ym9keV8xJGdsb2JhbF8xJHR3b2NvbHVtbnNyaWdodF8zJGFsZXJ0c1JOU0NhdGVnb3J5Q2hrXzEFOGJvZHlfMSRnbG9iYWxfMSR0d29jb2x1bW5zcmlnaHRfMyRhbGVydHNSTlNDYXRlZ29yeUNoa18yBThib2R5XzEkZ2xvYmFsXzEkdHdvY29sdW1uc3JpZ2h0XzMkYWxlcnRzUk5TQ2F0ZWdvcnlDaGtfMwU4Ym9keV8xJGdsb2JhbF8xJHR3b2NvbHVtbnNyaWdodF8zJGFsZXJ0c1JOU0NhdGVnb3J5Q2hrXzQFOGJvZHlfMSRnbG9iYWxfMSR0d29jb2x1bW5zcmlnaHRfMyRhbGVydHNSTlNDYXRlZ29yeUNoa181BThib2R5XzEkZ2xvYmFsXzEkdHdvY29sdW1uc3JpZ2h0XzMkYWxlcnRzUk5TQ2F0ZWdvcnlDaGtfNgU4Ym9keV8xJGdsb2JhbF8xJHR3b2NvbHVtbnNyaWdodF8zJGFsZXJ0c0xhbmd1YWdlc0xpc3RCb3gFP2JvZHlfMSRnbG9iYWxfMSR0d29jb2x1bW5zcmlnaHRfMyRhbGVydHNUZXJtc0NvbmRpdGlvbnNZZXNSYWRpbwU+Ym9keV8xJGdsb2JhbF8xJHR3b2NvbHVtbnNyaWdodF8zJGFsZXJ0c1Rlcm1zQ29uZGl0aW9uc05vUmFkaW8FPmJvZHlfMSRnbG9iYWxfMSR0d29jb2x1bW5zcmlnaHRfMyRhbGVydHNUZXJtc0NvbmRpdGlvbnNOb1JhZGlvulpIpatDBOMCMBv4U0RYSLazybs=" />
    </div>

    <div>

        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWFALT6IybBwK12ZCYCgL2hrCVDQKx6Oq/BQKvrM3CAgLk78yLBgLl78yLBgKN4Yb+AQL27ZH1DQL27dXjAwL27em+DAL27a2tAgL27cGICwL27YV3AszllaIKArua5/UCAo3Dqa0OAsr3g8gDAuW5heMGApqBqc4CprBsaYlxC8dTfOwmP1U0NzwPiic=" />
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['MainForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.MainForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

My code starts from here:

```
<div id="globalWrapper">

<p>my all coded html comes here</p>
--

---
---
---
---


</div>
```

This is end of body with extra WebResource.axd file

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=4AEhmjo4PfjXcTYk5tSDFQ2&amp;t=633912595699095000" type="text/javascript"></script>
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

I invest so much time to make my XHTML clean but I can't control this unwanted code. Is there a way to get clean code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ASP.NET MVC if you don't want to deal with ViewState, theForm and other WebForms related issues.

The hidden fields that are visible from the markup you pasted form the core of ASP.NET WebFormns. It is quite long to describe here what is it all about, the topic is kinda big. The short answer is that you need all this if you want to properly use ASP.NET WebForms. You can take a look at [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx) you really want to understand what is the ViewState and what purposes it serves.

As for the axd link that you see, this is specially designated ASP.NET handler that servers for shipping javascript files to your page. It is automatically added to your rendered markup if there is ScriptManager in your aspx page.

Comment: so you mean if i need clean code then i should use asp.net MVC based framework based CMS, or any other technology ,Php for example, clean code is not possible in Asp.net webform.